# problema al pasar DataGridView a otro formulario

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

Tengo un DataGridView cargado desde la BD y cuando selecciono una fila para mandarla al otro formulario me manda el mismo dato repetido varias veces 
este es le coddigo

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            frm.tblarticulo.Rows.Add();
            frm.tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["descripcion"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value;
            frm.tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["cantidad"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value;
            frm.tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["precio"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value;
            frm.tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["valtotal"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value;

        }
```

Este es el formulario del cual tomo los datos 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al pasarlos al otro formulario me lo manda asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como hago para que solo me pase el que seleccione ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar al otro `DataGridView` todas las filas que tienen el mismo código que la fila seleccionada, suponiendo que el `DataGridView` de origen se nombra `dataGridView1`, aquí si es necesario hacer un lazo, lo hago con un bloque `foreach`

Este es el procedimiento que captura las filas en el DataGridView`de origen y las envía al DataGridView` de destino.

```
private void EnviarFilas()
{
    //Capturamos el código de la fila seleccionada
    string codigoSelec = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    //Creamos un colección para almacenar todas las filas cuyo código es igual al seleccionado
    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow> coleccFilas =
        new System.Collections.Generic.List<DataGridViewRow>();
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow FilaActual in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (FilaActual.Cells[0].Value != null && FilaActual.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == codigoSelec)
        {
            coleccFilas.Add(FilaActual);
        }
    }
    //Ya tenemos en la variable coleccFilas todas las que su código es igual a codigoSelec
    //Llamamos al procedimiento mandaraotroformulario 
    mandaraotroformulario(coleccFilas);
}
```

En este código agregamos al `DataGridView` `frm.tblarticulo` las filas capturadas en el procedimiento anterior.

```
public void mandaraotroformulario(
    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow> colFilasSel)
{
    //Hacemos un foreach por la colección de filas capturadas
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow Fila in colFilasSel)
    {
        int index = frm.tblarticulo.Rows.Add();
        frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["descripcion"].Value = Fila.Cells[5].Value;
        frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["cantidad"].Value = Fila.Cells[6].Value;
        frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["precio"].Value = Fila.Cells[7].Value;
        frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["valtotal"].Value = Fila.Cells[8].Value;
    }
}
```

Existen otras opciones para lograr este resultado, pero con la información que brindas en tu pregunta es lo que veo mas acertado.

Comment: @Carlos Lo prometido es deuda, creo que esta respuesta te satisfaga, si te resulta útil te agradecería que marcaras como correcta y que puntearas, esta respuesta.

Comment: tengo una duda, es que los datos los mando por un boton entoces `mandaraotroformulario(coleccFilas);`  en esta parte me manda error igual que en esta `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow> colFilasSel)` al agregarlo

Comment: aunque utilice el código de arriba y se lo agregue me funciono en cierta parte , solo que al mandarlos me manda la misma fila la cantidad de veces que este el código repetido

Comment: @Carlos Puedo garantizarte que si implementas correctamente el código que coloque en el procedimiento ´EnviarFilas´ y pasas como argumento la colección ´coleccFilas´ al procedimiento que coloca en el ´DataGridView´ secundario los valores de las filas capturadas e implementas correctamente el procedimiento ´mandaraotroformulario´ o como quieras llamarle; el resultado no puede ser el de una sola fila, es muy difícil solo a nivel de comentario corregir tu código, te recomiendo que formules una nueva pregunta y coloques lo que hiciste en código para poder revisarlo, agradecería que me notifiques.

Comment: ok, lo voy a hacer

Comment: @Carlos Cuando coloques la pregunta, le agregas un comentario, haciendo referencia mi nombre de usuario, para recibir la notificación y saber que ya publicaste tu pregunta y poder localizarla.

Comment: ya formule la otra pregunta  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333838/problema-al-pasar-datagridview

Answer (score 1):

En tu código, solo está pasando el articulo que seleccionaste en el `dataGridView1` pero lo estas replicando tantas veces como filas tiene el `dataGridView1`, date cuenta que si haces un ciclo `for` ejecutaras el código ese número de veces; si solo quieres es colocarlo una ves en `frm.tblarticulo` pues no tienes que hacer ningún ciclo `for`, basta con hacer lo siguiente

```
public void mandaraotroformulario()
{
   int index =  frm.tblarticulo.Rows.Add();
   frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["descripcion"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value;
   frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["cantidad"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value;
   frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["precio"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value;
   frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["valtotal"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value;

}
```

Y así habrás pasado los valores de la fila seleccionada en `dataGridView1` a la fila creada en `frm.tblarticulo`

Comment: otra pregunta como hago para que me traiga todos los que tienen el mismo codigo

Comment: @Carlos Bueno esa es otra pregunta, me gustaría primero que si crees correcto la respuesta que te dí, que la marcaras como correcta y la puntearas, soy nuevo en el sitio y me seria de estimulo recibir tu puntuación, a continuación trataré de ayudarte con tu nueva interrogante.

Comment: @Carlos Estoy elaborando tu nueva respuesta.

Comment: ok, te lo agradeceria