# problema al pasar datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo un datagridview cargado desde la BD y cuando lo paso al otro formulario me pasa el mismo dato repetido

Este es el datagridview cargado desde la BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como me manda los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que utilizo:

```
foreach (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow FilaActual in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string codigoSelec = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow> coleccFilas = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DataGridViewRow>();

            if (FilaActual.Cells[0].Value != null && FilaActual.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == codigoSelec)
            {
                coleccFilas.Add(FilaActual);
                int index = frm.tblarticulo.Rows.Add();
                frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["descripcion"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value;
                frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["cantidad"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value;
                frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["precio"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value;
                frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["valtotal"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Eduardo Reyes Listo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya está claro que has querido hacer todo lo que indique en la respuesta a la pregunta anterior en un solo procedimiento y no en dos como te expuse en aquella repuesta, aquella fue una forma con la que intenté explicarte, es posible hacerlo en un solo procedimiento como los has intentado hacer, solo que hay que ser consecuente con lo que deseas lograr. Te coloco a continuación el código de como debería quedar tu `foreach` para hacerlo de una sola ves.

```
        foreach (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow FilaActual in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (FilaActual.Cells[0].Value != null && FilaActual.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == 
                dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
            {
                int index = frm.tblarticulo.Rows.Add();
                frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["descripcion"].Value = FilaActual.Cells[5].Value;
                frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["cantidad"].Value = FilaActual.Cells[6].Value;
                frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["precio"].Value = FilaActual.Cells[7].Value;
                frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["valtotal"].Value = FilaActual.Cells[8].Value;
            }
        }
```

Copia y pega  este código y pruebalo y puedo asegurarte que va a funcionar, el error en tu caso radica en que al asignar valores siempre haces referencia a `dataGridView1.CurrentRow`, que es la misma fila, en mi respuesta se hace referencia a la fila actual del bloque `foreach` que cambia en cada ciclo que ejecuta el bloque.
Tu haces lo siguiente:

```
frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["descripcion"].Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value;
```

Y yo hago lo siguiente:

```
frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["descripcion"].Value = FilaActual.Cells[5].Value;
```

La referencia `FilaActual.Cells[5].Value` hace la diferencia, eliminé además otras lineas de código que para hacerlo en un solo procedimiento no son necesarias. Pruebalo, dará resultados y no olvides marcar y puntear la respuesta.

Comment: Me ha funcionado, muchas gracias

Comment: @Carlos Por nada amigo, me alegro que hayas resuelto tu duda y gracias por tus votos. Éxitos en tu vida como desarrollador.

Comment: @EduardoReyes: Un consejo amigo desarrollador. Comentarios como: *"Pruebalo, dará resultados y no olvides marcar y puntear la respuesta."* creo que no van en la línea ética de este sitio. El usuario que formula la pregunta, ya sabrá si valorarte o no. Aún así, puedes dejar ese tipo de opiniones en la sección de comentarios, si tu respuesta ha sido útil.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta: Gracias por su consejo, realmente soy nuevo en el sitio y no estoy al tanto de todos esos codigos, realmente lo hice con la intención de lograr niveles de reputación, que creo me permitirían participar más activamente en el sitio y modestamente poder aportar mis experiencias, agradezco mucho su consejo, pues cuando respondo no es mi objetivo solo tratar de lograr mayor reputación.

Comment: @EduardoReyes: Perfecto, veo que has captado el consejo. Muy buena respuesta de todos modos, te doy 10 pts.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta Gracias por el consejo y por lo puntos.